# Ethernet over power. Does it need this filter?

Tags: ac, ethernet

Firstly, I can't find any answers for Ethernet over Power. Everything comes up with Power over Ethernet. Also I am a total noob, especially with AC.

I am using TP-Link Powerline devices in my house and want to put one outside in the garden. But they don't make an outside Powerline adapter. So I am really just reboxing one to be able to install it in my garden.

I have TP LINK TL-PA4020P Ethernet over power, wireless adapters.

One has been stripped down to be installed a powerbox for the garden.
(Relaxdays Gartensteckdose mit Zeitschaltuhr 2-fach Buchse plus Erdspieß, 10018965)
I have removed the timer unit and 3D printed a mount for the circuit board.

As these units have power passthrough, there is a little extra circuitboard with 2 coils around a core, one on each of the ac pins and a 1uf capacitor on one side. I guess this is some kind of filter.
[image: Original Circuit]

However, this doesn't seem to affect the Ethernet over power module. It appears to me, to only be engaged if an extra device is plugged into the passthrough socket. This device also works perfectly well plugged into a powerboard.

Now finally the question. Do I need to include the filter?
Should I do this, including the filter:
[image: Possible setup with filter]

Or can I just leave the filter out? Don't have the rep to add a picture of the simplified design, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I bet you got the circuit wrong. 1u cap cannot be in series like that.

Comment: please ignore the numbers, this is just a sketch. But the capacitor is installed like that.

Comment: @Eddie _"But the capacitor is installed like that."_ I share Dmitry's scepticism; it wouldn't pass a lot of current to the socket, making it useless for almost anything. Probably it's not a capacitor at all, or you're wrong about how it's wired.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a filter designed to protect sensitive devices you plug into the power socket from interference created by Ethernet module. Most of household equipment would work without this filter, but sensitive circuits like TV tuners and amplifiers may pick up this interference, and their performance may be affected. Note that modern sensitive equipment usually includes such filters internally if they are needed. Furthermore, devices connected downstream (past the wall socket) won't benefit from this filter at all.

You could try to connect the modules without this filter and check if all your electronics still works in presence of Ethernet traffic.

Comment: Well it's going in the garden, so the equipment will be things like a lawn mower or some lights when we have a party. Sounds like I can leave it out.

Comment: I have a guitar effects pedal sthat really hates power line networking...